# How to make variable that's in an array format into an array

Tags: php, arrays

This is probably a simple question, but how do I take a variable like the following and make it into an array.

```
    $hot = "It","is","hot","outside";
```

Doing the following doesn't work:

```
    $newhot = array($hot);
```

I'm actually calling an API that looks like:

```
    [["P0010001","NAME","state","zip code tabulation area"],
    ["68191","ZCTA5 99301","53","99301"]]
```

What I need is the population on the second line (first quotes).

Doing the following gives me "68191","ZCTA5 99301","53","99301"

```
    $splitContent = implode("\n",array_slice(explode("\n",$populate),1,2));
    $newContent = str_replace(']','',$splitContent);
    $newContent = str_replace('[','',$newContent);
```

Comment: That looks like a syntax error.

Comment: $hot = "It","is","hot","outside"; isn't a variable

Comment: `json_decode($populate);` ?

Comment: Doing: $NewContent = json_decode($populate);
echo $NewContent[0]; returns Array on the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
$hot = "It","is","hot","outside";
```

will generate error in PHP. But let's say you have the following retrieved from the API:

```
$str='[["P0010001","NAME","state","zip code tabulation area"],["68191","ZCTA5 99301","53","99301"]]';
```

then, if you run this line:

```
$myArray = json_decode($str);
```

and then

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myArray);
echo"</pre>";
```

you can have this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => P0010001
            [1] => NAME
            [2] => state
            [3] => zip code tabulation area
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 68191
            [1] => ZCTA5 99301
            [2] => 53
            [3] => 99301
        )

)
```

Second line of data will be stored in

```
$myArray[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Defining an array is something like...

```
$hot = array("It","is","hot","outside");
```

Re: Your Api call...

```
$ApiResponse = '[["P0010001","NAME","state","zip code tabulation area"],["68191","ZCTA5 99301","53","99301"]]';

$Response = json_decode($ApiResponse);
$Data = $Response[1];
```

Specifically, the api is returning a list of lists. We're taking the 2nd (0-indexed) list. `$Data` will now be the same as if you'd declared...

```
$Data = array("68191","ZCTA5 99301","53","99301");
```

Edit: Tested Code...

```
$Key = '[Your Key]';
$ApiResponse = file_get_contents("http://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1?key={$Key}&get=P0010001,NAME&for=zip+code+tabulation+area:99301&in=state:53");

print "Raw: " . print_r($ApiResponse, true) . "<hr/>";

$Response = json_decode($ApiResponse);
$Data = $Response[1];
print "Extracted Data: " . print_r($Data, true) . "<br/>";

print "First bit of data: {$Data[0]}.<br/>";
print "Second bit of data: {$Data[1]}.<br/>";
```

Comment: I can't do the first. The results are already in an variable. I need to turn the results in the variable into an array.

Comment: The syntax in your first (edited out) code snippet is invalid. If _all_ the results are in a variable, it's either an array (problem solved) or it's a string representation of a json array - in which case, use `json_decode`. There's no such thing as a variable with multiple values which isn't an array (or object/list/etc)

Comment: $populate = file_get_contents('http://apisite.com');
        $NewContent = json_decode($populate)[1];
        echo $NewContent[1]; -- Doesn't work.. get server error. I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrect.

Comment: You've got two `[1]`'s in there. if you want to see a whole object, use `print_r`. Something like... `file_get_contents('apisite.com'); $NewContent = json_decode($populate)[1]; print_r($NewContent);`. You haven't indicated if it worked or there was a problem?

Comment: No. It's not working. If I put [1] after ($populate) I get a server error. If I leave out [1] and do 'echo $NewContent' then it prints the word 'Array'. If I try doing 'echo $NewContent[1]' it also returns a server error.

Comment: And what happens if you use `print_r` instead of echo? If you can share the Api Url, I can knock up a PHPFiddle showing you how it needs to work

Comment: Using print_r gives a server error either way which indicates some kind of syntax error but there isn't as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can you share the Api url?

Comment: http://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1?key={key}&get=P0010001,NAME&for=zip+code+tabulation+area:99301&in=state:53 -- You'll have to get a unique key from http://www.census.gov/developers/tos/key_request.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29699/discussion-between-basic-and-jeight)

Comment: It was a syntax error. print_r(json_decode($populate)); gives me Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => P0010001 [1] => NAME [2] => state [3] => zip code tabulation area ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 68191 [1] => ZCTA5 99301 [2] => 53 [3] => 99301 ) )

Comment: Thank you for your time Basic. I appreciate it very much!!